# Formatting output of CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv, format

I am creating a very rudimentary "Address Book" program in Python.  I am grabbing contact data from a CSV file, the contents of which looks like the following example:

```
Name,Phone,Company,Email
Elon Musk,454-6723,SpaceX,emusk@spacex.com
Larry Page,853-0653,Google,lpage@gmail.com
Tim Cook,133-0419,Apple,tcook@apple.com
Steve Ballmer,456-7893,Developers!,sballmer@bluescreen.com
```

I am trying to format the output so that it looks cleaner and more readable, i.e. everything lined up in rows and columns, like this:

```
Name:        Phone:        Company:        Email:        
Elon Musk    454-6723      SpaceX          emusk@spacex.com
```

My current code is as follows:

```
f = open("contactlist.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    print(row)
```

Which naturally due to lack of formatting, produces this, which still looks very unclean.

```
['Name', 'Phone', 'Company', 'Email']
['Elon Musk', '454-6723', 'SpaceX', 'emusk@spacex.com']
['Larry Page', '853-0653', 'Google', 'lpage@gmail.com']
['Tim Cook', '133-0419', 'Apple', 'tcook@apple.com']
['Steve Ballmer', '456-7893', 'Developers!', 'sballmer@bluescreen.com']
```

Any tips on how to produce a cleaner output would be greatly appreciated, as I am beginner and I find all of this quite confusing.  Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use `format` to left justify your output. For example,

```
f = open("contactlist.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_f:
    print('{:<15}  {:<15}  {:<20} {:<25}'.format(*row))
```

Output:

```
Name             Phone            Company              Email                    
Elon Musk        454-6723         SpaceX               emusk@spacex.com         
Larry Page       853-0653         Google               lpage@gmail.com          
Tim Cook         133-0419         Apple                tcook@apple.com          
Steve Ballmer    456-7893         Developers!          sballmer@bluescreen.com
```

You can read more about [format here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language). The `<` symbol left-aligns the text, and the number specifies the width of the string. Each `{}` can include a positional argument before the colon `:` - if they are omitted, the strings will appear in the order of the arguments in the unpacked list `row`.

Comment: @zarak I tried your solution, but I keep getting IndexError: tuple index out of range any ideas for a solution?

Comment: Hi @Vash, Are you running the code on the example shown here?

Comment: @zarak No, i tried running it on a bigger csv file.

Answer (score 3):

There are a few python modules for creating tables through plain text, e.g. [tabulate](https://pypi.org/project/tabulate/) and [prettytable](https://pypi.org/project/prettytable/). With tabulate the printing becomes a one-liner:

```
from tabulate import tabulate
f = open("contactlist.csv")
csv_f = csv.reader(f)
print(tabulate(csv_f, headers='firstrow'))
```

The output looks like this:

```
Name           Phone     Company      Email
-------------  --------  -----------  -----------------------
Elon Musk      454-6723  SpaceX       emusk@spacex.com
Larry Page     853-0653  Google       lpage@gmail.com
Tim Cook       133-0419  Apple        tcook@apple.com
Steve Ballmer  456-7893  Developers!  sballmer@bluescreen.com
```

You can also specify among a bunch of formatting options with the `tablefmt` keyword. The output of `print(tabulate(csv_f,headers='firstrow', tablefmt='pipe'))` for example corresponds to markdown table format:

```
| Name          | Phone    | Company     | Email                   |
|---------------|----------|-------------|-------------------------|
| Elon Musk     | 454-6723 | SpaceX      | emusk@spacex.com        |
| Larry Page    | 853-0653 | Google      | lpage@gmail.com         |
| Tim Cook      | 133-0419 | Apple       | tcook@apple.com         |
| Steve Ballmer | 456-7893 | Developers! | sballmer@bluescreen.com |
```