# How to fix rendering issues in Python script

Tags: python, rendering, html

I have written a python script that reads a csv file and displays it on a web page. The web page is a simple html.

I am trying to display it with a certain format. I have searched through  stackoverflow and found this:
[Formatting output of CSV file in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39176935/formatting-output-of-csv-file-in-python)
which was helpful.

However, it works fine when using the `print` function but when I try to render into my webpage the format is not the same and it also displays only one line of result instead of the whole file.

So how can I have it display on my webpage the same format it displays on the python shell?

Here's what I have so far:

```
@app.route('/results/view')
def my_results():

        with open(str(get_file(filename)), "r") as f:
            content = csv.reader(f)
            for row in content:
                content =(('{:^15}  {:^15}  {:^20} {:^25}'.format(*row)))

            return render_template("results.html",content=content)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.debug = True #Uncomment to enable debugging
    app.run() #Run the Server
```

results.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>My webpage</title>
</head>
<body>
  <a>{{ content }}</a>
</body>
</html>
```

results w/ `print` statement instead of `'content='` (what I want)

```
  A       B
 blue     Car
 yellow   Bike
 green    Boat
```

result I am getting with `content =`

```
A green B Boat
```

Answer (score 0):

With:

```
    content = csv.reader(f)
    for row in content:
        content =(('{:^15}  {:^15}  {:^20} {:^25}'.format(*row)))
```

You are:

- assigning the content of the csv to `content`
- iterating through `content`
- assigning a formatted string to `content` (with `print` you don't have this step)

So `content` is overwritten at each iteration.

You probably want something like:

```
    content = csv.reader(f)
    html_content=""
    for row in content:
        html_content += (('{:^15}  {:^15}  {:^20} {:^25}'.format(*row)))
        html_content += "<br>" #or p/div/…
```

And then `return render_template("results.html",content=html_content)`.

Or

```
    content = csv.reader(f)
    html_content=[]
    for row in content:
        html_content.append(('{:^15}  {:^15}  {:^20} {:^25}'.format(*row)))
```

And then do a for loop in your view. Using jinja, something like:

```
{% for row in content %}
  <p>{{ row|e }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. Although, your suggestion works as far as display all the results, it still doesn't format correctly. It is just a long line with no breaks

Comment: Did you add `html_content += "<br>"`? maybe they are escaped?

Comment: I did. The '<br>' just gets printed in between the results. So A<br> blue<br>car ...

Comment: Your template engine is escaping html tags (which is a good thing actually). Using the second solution (passing a list to the template and iterating over it in the template) will avoid this problem. Also, in HTML, a sequence of N consecutive whitespaces is treated as one single space, so your line formatting won't work either. If you want to display tabular data, use the proper html tags (table / th / tr / td) instead.

Comment: I am using flask but it sort of worked. Now it prints one letter at every line. I'll update my answer once get it right.

Comment: either use `.append` or `+= [ ... ]`

Answer (score 0):

After a bit of research I found this [Python dictionary in to html table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14652325/python-dictionary-in-to-html-table)
which is was needed.

Fredtantini's answer was close. I needed an additional nested for loop in my html code.

```
<table>
{% for row in content %}
    <tr>
    {% for i in row %}
        <td>{{ i}}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
 </table>
```

This worked for me